# ImageMagick DePolarDistortion

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I would like to implement ImageMagick's "DePolarDistortion" functionality in my C# application (I'm using: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ImageMagick_in_VBNET.aspx).

Could you please give me a working example on how to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont see a problem ...

1) In the same solution as your ImageMagick .NET wrapper, create a C# Windows Application project in Visual Studio.

2) Add a reference from your C#.NET project to the ImageMagick .NET wrapper project

3) In the .cs file, put the following line at the top of the file:

```
       using ImageMagickNET
```

4) Make an UI like on this page ...

5) Transform code from VB to C# ...

6) Done !